# Stream of running sums in Scala

Tags: scala, stream

This is a follow-up to my previous question.
Given function `add_stream(s1:Stream[Int], s2:Stream[Int]):Stream[Int]` 
I would like to code `running_sums(s:Stream[Int]):Stream[Int]`, which returns a new stream : `s1, s1 + s2, s1 + s2 + s3, ...`

I can think of the following implementation but it does not work if `s` is empty

```
def running_sums(s:Stream[Int]):Stream[Int] =
  Stream.cons(s.head, add_streams(s.tail, running_sums(s)))
```

I can fix it as follows:

```
def running_sums(s:Stream[Int]):Stream[Int] =
  if (s.isEmpty) empty
    else Stream.cons(s.head, add_streams(s.tail, running_sums(s)))
```

However it does not look elegant.

How would you implement `running_sums`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a library call for something like this, called scanLeft

```
s.scanLeft(0)(_+_).tail
```

Answer (score 5):

What about `scanLeft`?

```
scala> val sums = stream.scanLeft(List(0))((ns, n) => ns :+ (ns.last + n))
sums: scala.collection.immutable.Stream[List[Int]] = Stream(List(0), ?)

scala> sums take 5 foreach println
List(0)
List(0, 1)
List(0, 1, 3)
List(0, 1, 3, 6)
List(0, 1, 3, 6, 10)
```